# What do I look for in an API response to get the fields?

Tags: c#

I want to display the number of players online, using this api query. I got stuck receiving the number of players in the message.

I use the following code in script:

```
SampQuery api = new SampQuery("184.103.47.77", 7777, 'i');

string sStatus = String.Format("Online players: {0}", /* STUCK HERE */);
onlinePlayers.Text = sStatus;
```

How can I get data from the `api` variable into the status string?

This is the API I'm using:

> https://github.com/zeelorenc/SA-MP-Server-Query-Class

Comment: `var data = api.read(true); Console.WriteLine(data["players"]);`? If you use the quickstart code and use your debugger, you'll be able to figure out the rest. The library returns a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you'll be able to access data using the key. The keys that are populated are seen in the code [here](https://github.com/zeelorenc/SA-MP-Server-Query-Class/blob/master/SampQueryApi.cs#L121).

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linked example, you need to do four things:

1. Call `api.Read()`, as shown in the sample. So far, you have only set up an API call. You don't actually talk to the API until you call the `read()` method. Don't forget to assign the result to a variable.
2. Run **ALL** the code in the sample. This will print out a list of key/value pairs. That will tell you what fields are available in the API.
3. Look at the output from step #2, to figure out what key you need.
4. Use the key identified in step 3 to create the expression for your `/* Stuck here */` comment